# Using Moment react in an array and then format Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I want to format a Date (StartDate and EndDate) in Moment React. Unfortunately, it's always giving me an error message.

Maybe you can help me!

Here is my code so far:

```
this.state.ProjectFilterItem.forEach((item:IListItem)=> project.push(

   
  <div className={styles.containerGrid}>
       
    <div className={styles.ProjectTitleHeader}>item 1 {item.Title}</div>
      <div className={styles.imageTL}>
      <img src={item.TrafficLight?.Title == "Green" ? 'https://url/sites/PMO-PoC/Shared%20Documents/TrafficLight/TrafficLight-green.png':
                item.TrafficLight?.Title == "Yellow" ? 'https://url/sites/PMO-PoC/Shared%20Documents/TrafficLight/TrafficLight-yellow.png':
                 item.TrafficLight?.Title == "Red" ? 'https://url.sharepoint.com/sites/PMO-PoC/Shared%20Documents/TrafficLight/TrafficLight-red.png': ''}></img>
       </div>
    <div className={styles.ProjectStartdate}>item 3 {moment({item.StartDate}).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}</div>
    <div className={styles.ProjectEnddate}> item 4 {item.EndDate}</div>
    <div className={styles.ProjectStatus}>item 5 {item.ProjectStatus?.Title}</div>
    <div className={styles.ProjectPhase}>item 6 {item.ProjectPhase?.Title}</div>
  </div>
))
```

Comment: What is the error message? Can you try this: `moment(new Date(item.StartDate)).format('DD.MM.YYYY')`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: did you try above suggestion? is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<div className={styles.ProjectStartdate}>item 3 {moment({item.StartDate}).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}</div>
```

**Use this**:

```
<div className={styles.ProjectStartdate}>item 3 {moment(new Date(item.StartDate)).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}</div>
```

**Documentation**: [Moment JS Docs](https://momentjs.com/)